# is it possible to scrape list of followers of a public twitter acount (page)

Tags: python, twitter, web-scraping, text-mining, scrape

i am student and i am totally new to scraping etc, today my supervisor gave me task to get the list of followers of a user or page(celebrity etc)
the list should contain information about every user (i.e user name, screen name etc)

After a long search i found that i can't get the age and gender of any user on twitter.
secondly i got help regarding getting list of my followers but i couldnt find help about "how i can get user list of public account"

kindly suggest me that its possible or not, and if it is possible, what are the ways to get to my goals
thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Hardly so, and even if you manage to somehow do it, you'll most likely get blacklisted. Also, please read the community guidelines when it comes to posting questions.

Comment: brother i dont think so that someone can be blacklisted by doing so because its just public data. and i was just trying to scrape public data. just username screen name

Comment: It is public data but depending on the sheer quantity of requests you might be sending they might start tracking you, but if you have to or are keen on doing it, nothing's stopping you from trying.